# Search REST API - An unknown error occurred

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, refiner

Wondering if you could help me please, I am currently calling the SharePoint rest search api with a number of parameters as below:

```
GET: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol/_api/search/query?
querytext='path:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecol ContentTypeId:0x0101008CA34DF8F4904B3EB1EB49AC10614C68*'
&trimduplicates=false
&startrow=0
&rowlimit=1
&selectproperties='Write,Path,LastModifiedTime'&refiners='LastModifiedTime(discretize=manual/2017-12-01/2018-01-01/2018-03-01/2018-03-01/2018-04-01/2018-05-01/2018-06-01/2018-07-01/2018-08-01/2018-09-01/2018-10-01/2018-11-01/2018-12-01/2019-01-01/2019-03-01/2019-03-01/2019-04-01/2019-05-01/2019-06-01/2019-07-01,sort=name/descending,filter=99/1/*)'
&ClientType='ContentSearchRegular'
```

I am using the header **Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata**

However when running this in Postman or SharePoint online I get the following returned:

> {
>       "odata.error": {
>           "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException",
>           "message": {
>               "lang": "en-US",
>               "value": "An unknown error occurred."
>           }
>       }
>   }

The only method I appear to have found to fix this is to reduce the number of thresholds in the refiner parameter however I am unable to find any documentation detailing the maximum number of thresholds that can be used.

I appreciate any help that anyone can give on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation can be found at :

https://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/12/22/performing-a-search-request-with-sharepoint-rest-api-throws-a-microsoft-sharepoint-client-unknownerror/

You should specify Odata version as 3.0 and not 4.0 because the search API does not work with 4.0.